# Ruby on Rails Pie Chart Library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts

Is there any library that can produce server-side pie charts using Ruby?

Such as this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Gruff](https://github.com/topfunky/gruff) is pretty cool for this.

Answer (score 4):

This provides easy integration to your rails app by just one line of ruby code. hope this could help to anybody..

> https://github.com/ankane/chartkick

Answer (score 1):

Google's javascript charting library is ok for simple tasks
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

And there are a lot of gems that wrap GoogleCharts
http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/
https://github.com/mattetti/googlecharts

EDIT: Didn't see the server side constraint. Ignore my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

@bandito has given example of google javascript charting library. Well, there is `Chart API` from `Google` which sends back the required image, if you send the parameters in the API URL. See [Image Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/). There is a specific section for [pie charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/gallery/pie_charts.html) there. I have used it once and found it very useful. Ofcourse there is loading time for the chart, and limitations to how far it is customizable, but for a simple pie chart like the one shown in figure, I think this is adequate.

See the [getting started](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/making_charts.html) for understanding how the API works.

Also see [Chart Wizard](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard.html)

Answer (score 1):

For Rails, look at quacky-charts at https://github.com/ragingsquirrel3/quacky-charts

Comment: hey hey, in the interest of full disclosure next time maybe consider pointing out that this is a tool which you designed yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rchart](https://github.com/amardaxini/rchart) for plotting various chart.